# How to get text Strings order in Laravel project

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I would like to sort column like orderBy.

'WC' columns has such data

```
'AB-1' 'AB-2' 'AB-5' 'AB-300' 'AB-1980' .... etc
```

Front of "AB-" letter is same. then comes number.

Could you teach me how to write code please?

```
 public function index()
    {
        $images = ImageGallery::orderBy('wc', 'asc')->get();
        return view('image-gallery',compact('images'));
    }
```

Comment: your code should work, what is not happening correctly?

Comment: Are you getting any error ? your code seems correct. it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just order by the field, the result will be:

```
'AB-1' 'AB-1980' 'AB-2' 'AB-200' 'AB-3' 'AB-301'...
```

You can use order by the length of value, and then order by that field:

```php
ImageGallery::orderBy(DB::raw('LENGTH(wc), wc'))->get();
```

The result will be :

```
'AB-1' 'AB-2' 'AB-3' 'AB-200' 'AB-301' 'AB-1980' ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much! May I ask this How about using where? How can I add your code?   $images = ImageGallery::where('type', "0123")->get();

Comment: @greeniron u'r welcome. You can just apply `orderBy(DB::raw('LENGTH(wc), wc'))` to `where`.something like this: `$images = ImageGallery::where('type', "0123")->orderBy(DB::raw('LENGTH(wc), wc'))->get()`